# #define FUNC(x,y) x=^y; y^x; in c

Tags: c

Im having trubles to understand what it means when there is define and then two xor expressions. what this define does?

i try to send x=8, y=7 and the result was that x=15 and y=8
why its happand?

this is the program:

```
#define FUNC(a,b) a^=b; b ^=a;

int main(){
    int x=8,y= 7;
    FUNC(x,y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x, y);
}
```

Comment: Dont do that. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), then run your program step by step in  a debugger (`gdb`). Look also into the preprocessed form (`gcc -Wall -C -E`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Too lazy to compile -- what's the prob with the code?

Comment: Ureadable and error-prone; imagine an `if (x>0) FUNC(x,y);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You mean -- C? ;-). And: Yes, one should always use braces ;-).

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the `#define` or how the exclusive or (`^`) is working? The `#define` in C is actually very simple-minded. It takes what is defined and does a direct substitution. If you run the C preprocessor (`cpp`) and examine the output, you'll see what it does. In this case `FUNC(x, y)` will be replaced by `x^=y; y ^=x;` and the overall result statement will look like `x^=y; y ^=x;;` with the extra semicolon (because you have a semicolon after `FUNC(x, y)`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, the `#define` is a horrible practice but there's nothing "wrong" with the code. It compiles without warning.

Comment: What do **you** think the `#define` is supposed to do?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Here braces are bad, too. For the example using parenthesis and the _comma operator_ is the better (and portable) way. Of course using a macro where a function works, too is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf Well, I meant braces after the if() in Basile's example. Making the sequence a value as you suggest fixes, I think, the syntactical problems of a multi-statement define, but changes the semantics. Although, admittedly, I'd indeed expect a `FUNC()` to return something (as opposed to, say, a `PROC()`).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: EIther way, this is a good example of why (function) macros have such a bad reputation. I really wish tutors would sensitise their students about that subject from the beginning.

Comment: @Olaf I agree. Normally the compiler development (e.g. their ability to inline) has obviated the need for macros. There are very few places left where the preprocessor's operating on the source code proper is useful (like, create debug output with variable names in it).

Comment: Remember to "accept" your favourite answer; this allows SO to properly retire the question.

Answer (score 5):

It is just the same as

```
int main(){
    int x=8,y= 7;
    x^=y; y ^=x;;
    printf("%d %d\n",x, y);
}
```

because the define will just be a simple text substitution, i.e. all places with `a`will be replaced by `x` and all places with `b` will be replaced with `y`.

The `^` is a bit wise XOR operator.

So first `x = 8 ^ 7 = 15` then `y = 7 ^ 15 = 8`

This is because XOR produce `1` when one of the bits **but not both** are `1`

```
x =  8 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001000  // Assuming 32 bit int
y =  7 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000111  // Assuming 32 bit int
 x=x^y = 0b00000000000000000000000000001111 = 15

x = 15 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001111  // Assuming 32 bit int
y =  7 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000111  // Assuming 32 bit int
 y=y^x = 0b00000000000000000000000000001000 = 8
                                        ^^^
                                        Zero because both bits are 1
```

Comment: Actually, it would be `x^=y; y ^=x;;` (two semicolons), which is harmless but still.

Answer (score 2):

More to the original question:

This macro has the first two steps of the bit-wise method to exchange two values:

```
(1) a ^= b
(2) b ^= a
(3) a ^= b
```

Let's expand this a little: let x = a; y = b, and we'll trace the algebra through terms of x and y.  First, replace each "update" with its full expression:

```
(1) a = a ^ b
(2) b = b ^ a
(3) a = a ^ b
```

Now, substitute x and y, trickling down from top to bottom:

```
(1) a = x ^ y
(2) b = y ^ (x ^ y)
(3) a = (x ^ y) ^ (y ^ (x ^ y))
```

Drop the parentheses and rearrange terms:

```
(1) a = x ^ y
(2) b = x ^ y ^ y
(3) a = x ^ x ^ y ^ y ^ y
```

... leaving us with b = x; a = y

Now, since you have only the first two steps, your final result is

```
b = x (original value of a)
a = x ^ y (a.k.a. a ^ b)
```

Does that explain the immediate problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to #define multi-statement macros is

`#define FUNC() do { statement1; statement2; } while(0)`

That way even `if(b) FUNC();` does what the caller thinks.

There has been a discussion a few years ago which led to a change in the MISRA rules concerning this; MISRA does not recommend the "do" strategy any longer, because they say one should *always* use curly braces, as in `if(b) { FUNC(); }` which would handle unprotected multi-statement macros gracefully (and prevent bugs like the Apple certificate goto screw-up). Instead, a `do{...` would camouflage the failure to use braces.

I think I personally still side on the `do`side, if only because I know it.

CERT [recommends](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/PRE10-C.+Wrap+multistatement+macros+in+a+do-while+loop) the technique as well.

Comment: @Leeor Yes, what about it? I think you are missing the leading `do`, and thou shalt eternally bracket thy macro parameters.

Comment: @Leeor Apart from that -- you do not by any chance know Shir?

Comment: There is a lot bad to say about that kind of macros - and some are stated in your answer. However, I think the most important thing isn't part of your answer. That is "Always use () around arguments". So it should be `#define FUNC(a,b) do {(a)^=(b); (b) ^=(a);} while(0)` as this will find errors like `FUNC(x+y, x-y)`

Comment: @StillLearning, with or without parenthesis, x+y can't be an lvalue in this particular case, otherwise a simple x++ is enough to show this is bad (but both will produce a warning. @Peter, added the `do`, and I think it's compiling in c - i'm still not getting any warning. Either way, my point was that even this isn't safe and may fail silently.

Comment: @Leeor - In this particular case you'll get compiler error with or without parenthesis. But consider this `#define MUL10(a, b) a= b*10` and `int x=3; int y=2; MUL10(y, y + x);` - you would expect `y=50` but you'll get `y=32` due to the missing parenthesis. Doing ` `#define MUL10(a, b) (a)= (b)*10` solves the problem and produce the correct `y=50`. This shows why you shall always use parenthesis.